# Setting text of a radio button dynamically in Android

Tags: android, adt

I'm new to android, working on a project of quiz application in android with mysql. I want to set the text of radio buttons dynamically. How to access the individual radio buttons of a radiogroup, to set the text of each radio buttons in .java file? Kindly help me in solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use rb.setText("text");

Answer (score 2):

```
RadioGroup mGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
int count = mGroup.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0;i<count;i++){
    if(mGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof RadioButton)
        ((RadioButton) mGroup.getChildAt(i)).setText("Radio Button "+i);
}
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Create radiobuttons in youe xml file. get the radio buttons in your mainActivity of the app.

```
RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
```

Change the text associated with the button using the following metod

```
rb1.setText("new text");

this is how a xml of radio group looks like
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>

to access each radio button of a group you can use its name
example radio0,radio1,radio2 are the three radio buttons in a radio group
you can access it by 
RadioButton rb0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
rb0.setText("new text");
```

Comment: How to access individual radio buttons of a radiogroup?

Comment: this is how a radio group is created in xml